# httacces conflicts rewrite of user's profiles and user's posts

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

1) I have a htaccess who rewrites the User profile.

```
http://example.com/account.php?p=profile&username=Ernest
```

to `http://example.com/Ernest`

whith the next code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ account.php?p=profile&username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ account.php?p=profile&username=$1
```

It works good...

2) And the next httaccess which rewrites the user's posts

```
 http://example.com/account.php?p=post&id=12345678
```

to `http://example.com/post?id=12345678`

It works with the next httaccess

```
RewriteRule ^post$ account.php?p=post [QSA]
```

3) Everyone works good isolated, but at the moment I want to mix both htaccess codes in one file to have rewritten users profiles & posts. It fails! How should I do to make them work togheter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `post` rule before the other rule and have an exclusion rule before other all rules that will skip files and directories from rewriting.

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^post/?$ account.php?p=post [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ account.php?p=profile&username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also note that by using `/?$` in the regex, you can combine 2 rules into one.

Comment: But what does `-d` and `-f` means?

Comment: As the comment above that rule says. `-d` to detect a directory and `-f` to detect an existing file.

Comment: My friend sorry  for the belated reply. your code works well. Thanks you pretty much. but I have a last question. Why using `^([\w-]+)` instead of `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` for the user profile?

Comment: the rule `^([\w-]+)` you posted for users doesnt work for the next user `stack.overflow-for_all` for example.

Comment: `\w` is shortcut for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and even `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` won't match `stack.overflow-for_all` because there is a DOT as well. You can use `[\W.-]+` (see edited answer)

Comment: thanks you. I'll definitely accept your answer. you deserve it.